# Adding a new record through visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have created a select list which identifies the list of sales reps which are present in User table but not present in User_Stats__c table. Based on the selection in select list, I want to add record for that sales rep in User_Stats__c table. In particular, I want to add following fields: rep id (Sales_rep_*c), Month*_c, Year_*c, Goal*_c. What is the method to do this on visualforce page? Please help. I am stuck on this since some time now..

Controller code used for creating the select list:

```
public list <SelectOption> getAddosr()
    {
        List <selectoption> lsosradd = new List<selectoption> ();
        lsosradd.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
        List<String> newString = new List<String>();
        for(User_Stats__c ust : [SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0 and Sales_Rep__c != null])
        {
            newString.add(ust.Sales_Rep__c);
        }
        Set<String> repSet1 = new Set<String>();
        for (User srep :  [SELECT Name FROM User where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0 and Sales_Rep__c != null and Sales_Rep__c NOT IN: newString])
        {
            if(!repSet1.contains(srep.Name)) 
                    lsosradd.add(new selectoption(srep.Name, srep.Name));
            repSet1.add(srep.Name);
        }
        return lsosradd;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To add new record for the SalesRep you will need some reference to it. For this you have created SelectOption list `getAddosr()`. Here are basic steps to save record on visualforce page. Read about each component used here for clear understanding :-

Reference SelectOption list on visualforce pagelike this (Read about using `SelectList` [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm)):

```
<apex:selectList value="{!SalesRepId}" multiselect="true">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!Addosr}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Now add [`<apex:commandbutton>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)  on visualforce page and define action like this:

`<apex:commandButton action="{!saveNewRecord}" value="Save"/>`

Now create same method in controller class which is defined in above `action` attribute. like this:

```
public String salesRepId {get; set;} // initialise it in constructor

public void saveNewRecord()
{
    // Save logic using variable "salesRepId"
    // Ex: List<User> rep = [SELECT .. from User Where SalesRep__c in :salesRepId]
    // DML etc..
}
```

Also change line `lsosradd.add(new selectoption(srep.Name, srep.Name));` with `lsosradd.add(new selectoption(srep.Id, srep.Name));`